# Columnstore index proper usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, optimization

I just learned about the wonders of columnstore indexes and how you can "Use the columnstore index to achieve up to 10x query performance gains over traditional row-oriented storage, and up to 7x data compression over the uncompressed data size."

With such sizable performance gains, is there really any reason to NOT use them?

Comment: They are only really suitable for data warehouse workloads. Large tables, relatively infrequent data modifications, queries that access large numbers of rows. They should not be used for typical OLTP workloads.

Comment: [This paper explains how they are implemented BTW](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=193599) so you can see the trade offs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main disadvantage is that you'll have a hard time reading only a part of the index if the query contains a selective predicate. There are ways to do it (partitioning, segment elimination) but those are neither particularly easy to reliably implement nor do they scale to complex requirements.

For scan-only workloads columnstore indexes are pretty much ideal.

Comment: A predicate that filters out most rows, like selecting a single day or orders with a very rare status code.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you mean when you say "read only a part of the index"?

Comment: @Lopsided B-tree based indexes can be seeked. The query processor can read an arbitrary subrange of the index delimited by keys. E.g. the predicates `Email = ...` or `SomeCol > 3` read a range of the index. They don't touch the rest. This is hard to do with a columnstore index.

Answer (score 8):

Columnstore Indexes is especially beneficial for **DataWarehousing (DW)**. Meaning that you will only perform updates or deletes at certain times.

This is due to their special design with delta loading and more features. This video will show great detail and a nice basic overview of what the exact difference is [Columnstore Index](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=772Go3sewHI).

### Traditional

If you however have a high **I/O** (input and output) of the application; Columnstore Index is not ideal since traditional **row indexing** will find and manipulate (using the rows found through the index) on that specific target. An example of this would be a ATM application which frequently changes the values of the **rows** of the given persons accounts.

### ColumnStore

**Columnstore Indexing** indexes throughout the **COLUMNS** which is not ideal in this case since the row values will be spread throughout the segmentations (columnsindexes).

I highly recommend the video!

I want to also elaborate on the non-clustered vs clustered columnstore:

> Non-clustered Columnstore (update in 2012) saves the **WHOLE** data again meaning (2X data) twice the data.
>
> Where as Clustered Columnstore index (update in 2014) only takes up 5MB for about 16GB of data. This is due to the RTE (runtime encoding) which saves the amount of duplicate data in each column. Making the index take up less extra storage.

Answer (score 2):

Hello A very [detailed explanation of columns store index](http://geekprogrammers.com/question/what-is-columnstore-index-sql/) can be found [here](http://geekprogrammers.com/question/what-is-columnstore-index-sql/).

**ColumnStore Index**

A columnstore index is a technology for storing, retrieving and managing data by using a columnar data format, called a columnstore.

This feature has been introduced with SQL Server 2012 which intends to significantly speed-up the processing time of common data warehousing queries. The main objectives of columnstore indexes is appropriate for typical data warehousing data sets and improve the performance of the query whenever data is pulled from the huge datasets.

They are column based indexes which are capable to transform the data warehousing experience for users by enabling faster performance for common data warehousing queries such as filtering, aggregating, grouping and star-join queries. They store the data column-wise instead of row-wise, as indexes currently do.